# Dashclock widget example-extension Unable to instantiate service

Tags: android, dashclock

I'm trying to write [dashclock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwibmV0Lm51cmlrLnJvbWFuLmRhc2hjbG9jayJd) extension, so I started with the [example-extension](http://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/example-extension/)
but I can't get it work properly. I can see this example extension in dashclock settings in extensions list but it is not on the actual dashclock widget. It crashes in backgound periodically with this stack trace:

```
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.dashclock.exampleextension.ExampleExtension: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dashclock.exampleextension.ExampleExtension" on path: /data/app/com.example.dashclock.exampleextension-1.apk
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2513)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dashclock.exampleextension.ExampleExtension" on path: /data/app/com.example.dashclock.exampleextension-1.apk
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2510)
02-22 17:04:31.118: E/AndroidRuntime(25888):    ... 10 more
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.dashclock.exampleextension.ExampleExtension" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.dashclock.exampleextension-1.apk

This means that it cannot locate `ExampleExtension.java` which should be located in the `com.example.dash` `clock.exampleextension` package

---

First off, do not import the example files into eclipse, start a brand new Android Application

Deselect the create Activity button when it asks

After it is created, right click on the src folder and add a package.
Then right click the package and create a new class.
This new class will be your extension.
Get the 2 jar files from Dashclock site [here](http://code.google.com/p/dashclock/)

Drag them into your libs folder

Add this to your manifest

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_extension_yourIcon"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

    <service android:name=".YourExtension"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_extension_your_icon"
        android:label="@string/your_extension_title"
        android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="protocolVersion" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="description"
            android:value="@string/your_extension_description" />
    </service>

</application>
```

Save the Manifest, find the errors indicated by red lines and add the appropriate strings to your strings.xml

Here is an empty Extension class

```
    public class YourExtension extends DashClockExtension {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdateData(int reason) {

    publishUpdate(new ExtensionData()
    .visible(true)
    .icon(R.drawable.ic_extension_yourIcon)
    .status("This is the text when minimized")
    .expandedTitle("This is the white Title text when expanded")
    .expandedBody("This is the grey footer text when expanded")
    .clickIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))));

    }
    }
```

Comment: After following @jb15613, I get my extension to compile and show up in the extensions list. I'm getting 
`03-07 14:57:00.566: E/AndroidRuntime(14508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

`03-07 14:57:00.566: E/AndroidRuntime(14508): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.ExtensionData`

I've imported the api.jar and am getting no compilation errors in Eclipse. The class (ExtensionData) *is* there but cannot be seen.

Comment: There are to different Jar files on the site, you should import them both. What is the Class ExtensionData? In my extension, i have only one class, which is declared in the manifest

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am using Android studio. I have followed you guide but I still get the class not found error.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's not working after doing what jb15613 explained very well (I saw in comments people - like me - for whom it wasn't working), on IntelliJ, set in the module dependencies tab in project structure that you want it to provide the JAR as "Compile".